# Why query.get is faster than any alternative?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For Performance improvement of my `flask` app, I Just test one query with different approaches, I use `jupyter` `%timeit` magic command and run the following lines seperately (comments show the average time +- standard deviation of running the codes for multiple times).

```
u = User.query.get(39) # 32.1 µs ± 1.28 µs

u = User.query.filter_by(id=39).first() #97.8 ms ± 7.43 ms

u = db.session.query(User).filter_by(id=39).first() #89.2 ms ± 13.7 ms

u = db.session.query(User.id).filter_by(id=39).first() #74.6 ms ± 16.8 ms
```

As you can see the first approach approximately is 1000 times faster than other approaches?

Can anybody explain what is the difference between  using `query.get` and other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @georgexsh's answer could be more explanatory. SQLAlchemy uses a session-caching system, meaning that everything you queried from database gets stored in memory. This means that each time you invoke `.get()`, SQLAlchemy will first look into cache to determine whether the data requested has already been loaded to memory. If so, it is ready for display, otherwise it will go query the database.

By using caching, `.get()` requests **usually** take less time (note, after change in DB, it will take more time). This is particularly useful if your application is more of a serving thing than storing.

**Edit:** As stated in the comment, session is not cache, but as the documentation states, session can be interpreted as a sort of cache.

Comment: session is not cache: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-a-cache

Answer (score 4):

because of `query.get` is from the session, not from the database, quoted from [sqlalchemy doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get):

> get() is special in that it provides direct access to the identity map of the owning Session. If the given primary key identifier is present in the local identity map, the object is returned directly from this collection and no SQL is emitted, unless the object has been marked fully expired. If not present, a SELECT is performed in order to locate the object.